# Problem with fancyhdr and title page

Tags: fancyhdr

I would like the header and footer to show up also on the title page, but this is not happening. This question has been asked several times is different variations, over the years, for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326611/problem-with-title-page-fancy-header). @egreg's answer there did not work for me. In other posts I found that I had to add `\thispagestyle{fancy}` after `\maketitle`. I tried many variations and combinations but nothing has worked so far.

I am using the latest version of fancyhdr from 2019, which I installed following the instructions. I am using V 3.77 of TeXShop on a new Mac with OSX 10.14.6 (Mojave), and pdftex to compile.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.7,0,0}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm, top=1cm, right=2cm, includeheadfoot, margin=2cm, headheight=61pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Left Header}
\fancyhead[C]{Centre Header}
\fancyhead[R]{Right Header}
\fancyfoot[L]{\fbox{\parbox{15.03cm}
{\strut \textcolor{darkred}{\textbf{Left Footer}}}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\fbox{\parbox{1.5cm}{\strut\centering\thepage}}}
}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\title{titletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitle\\
titletitletitletitletitletitle}
\author{blabla}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of assigning hardcoded widths of 15.03cm and 1.5cm to the `\parbox`es in the definitions of `\fancyfoot[L]` and `\fancyfoot[R]`, respectively, you may want to write `\parbox{\dimexpr0.9\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}{...}` and `\parbox{\dimexpr0.1\textwidth-2\fboxsep-1\arrayrulewidth\relax}{...}`, respectively. That way, if you ever decide to change the margin widths, you don't have to recompute the widths of the `\parbox`es as well.

Comment: Thank you @Mico, that's a nice suggestion.

Comment: Alternatively, don't use \maketitle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default definition of `\maketitle` for the book class uses a titlepage environment (that takes up a whole page) which itself declares `\thispagestyle{empty}`. There is no opportunity to put `\thispagestyle{fancy}` on the same page as the title.

Headers on the title page of a book make no sense at all. You should probably be using a different document class that matches your document, which does not appear to be a book. Otherwise, redefine `\maketitle` to give the title page that you want.

The least satisfying answer is probably what you are looking for. Since the title page is forced to be "empty", restyle that to what you like.

```
\fancypagestyle{empty}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Left Header}
\fancyhead[C]{Centre Header}
\fancyhead[R]{Right Header}
\fancyfoot[L]{\fbox{\parbox{15.03cm}
{\strut \textcolor{darkred}{\textbf{Left Footer}}}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\fbox{\parbox{1.5cm}{\strut\centering\thepage}}}
}
```

Comment: +1 for "Headers on the title page of a book make no sense at all."

Comment: Thank you very much @Donald Arsenau for explaining why `\thispagestyle{fancy}` does not work. I am writing a report, not a book, so kudos for that observation too. I don't like headers on the title page of a report either, as it happens, but I did not set the typesetting rules for this writing task. I'll try the report class anyway, to see how it works. Finally, thanks for the "least satisfying answer" you provided. Perhaps not elegant from the Latex point of view, but the most "mathematically" satisfying answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've decided to disregard virtually all known conventions related to the design of title pages, I can see no reason for employing `\title`, `\author`, `\date`, and `\maketitle` macros. After all, these macros are there to make it straightforward to follow various layout conventions for title material. Why not just create your own title page, the way you see fit?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.7,0,0}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot, margin=2cm, headheight=61pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Left Header}
\fancyhead[C]{Centre Header}
\fancyhead[R]{Right Header}
\fancyfoot[L]{\fbox{%
  \parbox{\dimexpr0.9\textwidth-2\fboxsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}{%
          \strut\textcolor{darkred}{\textbf{Left Footer}}}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\fbox{%
  \parbox{\dimexpr0.1\textwidth-2\fboxsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}{%
          \strut\centering\thepage}}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% for now, just copy 'fancy' settings:
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Left Header}
\fancyhead[C]{Centre Header}
\fancyhead[R]{Right Header}
\fancyfoot[L]{\fbox{%
  \parbox{\dimexpr0.9\textwidth-2\fboxsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}{%
          \strut\textcolor{darkred}{\textbf{Left Footer}}}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\fbox{%
  \parbox{\dimexpr0.1\textwidth-2\fboxsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}{%
          \strut\centering\thepage}}}
}

%\title{titletitletitle titletitletitle titletitletitle\\
%titletitletitle titletitletitle}
%\author{blabla}

\begin{document}
%% make your own title page:
\null
\vspace{\fill}
\centering
{\huge titletitletitle titletitletitle titletitletitle\\
titletitletitle titletitletitle\par} % title stuff
\vspace{1cm}
{\Large Bla-bla Bla\par} % author stuff
\vspace{1cm}
{\large 1 June 2020} % date stuff
\vspace{\fill}
\clearpage

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{The Beginning}
\chapter{The End}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I haven't decided anything; I am simply following my limited understanding of the concepts, and through this site I rely on the kindness of strangers for the things I can't solve on my own. I share the wisdom of the RTFM point of view but the LaTeX universe is pretty big and I can't always invest the time. Anyway, good point about making my own custom page -- thank you, I should have thought of that.